# facebook graph api how to view this url obtained from api

Tags: facebook-graph-api

i am using facebook graph api for getting the posts of a page.

In that i have the following for one of the posts:

```
"picture": "fbstaging://graph.facebook.com/staging_resources/MDExMDE1NDIxMjc1MTM3NzU1NjoxNTkyMDk5MzA4
```

How can i get the image from the above link.

Comment: Staging Images are part of the Object API, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/opengraph/object-api#objectapi-images Those URLs are for internal use only, and can not be used to reference an actual image outside of Facebook. I am not sure though, whether the API should return those (and not rather a FB CDN URL for the actual image instead) when you request the feed data of a page – suggest you file a bug report and ask for clarification.

Comment: And i what i understand is, those images are only seen in facebook.com/pagename.